# Functional Programming approach to a REST API example

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I would like to know if there are any things I could improve with the following code regarding writing it in a FP style:

`server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const person = require('./person');

app.get('/create-person/:name', (req, res) => {
    person.addPerson(req.params.name);
    res.sendStatus(201);
});

app.get('/get-person/:name', function (req, res) {
    res.json(person.getPerson(req.params.name));
})

app.listen(3000);
```

`person.js`:

```
// Impure
let personList = [];
// Impure
function set(newPersonList) {
    personList = newPersonList;
    console.log(personList);
}
// Pure
function createPerson(name) {
    return {
        name
    };
}
// Pure
function addPerson(name, createPersonArg = createPerson, personListArg = personList, setArg = set) {
    return setArg([...personListArg, createPersonArg(name)]);
}
// Pure
function getPerson(name, personListArg = personList) {
    return personListArg.find((person) => {
        return name === person.name
    });
}

module.exports = {
    addPerson,
    getPerson
}
```

I'm using default parameters. I'm also wondering if this is the correct way of using them in FP.

I am aware I am creating a resource with GET. So ignore that, it is for being able to use the browser quickly to create a resource in this example.

Comment: In regards to your REST API. It is common to send POST instead of GET to create a resource. The HTTP methods (verbs) are meant exactly for this differentiation between operations. Use `POST /person` to create new person. Use `PATCH /person/:name` to update existing person. And `GET /person/:name` to get existing person's data. Or at least that is the usual way...

Comment: @slepic Please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I don't think my comment makes for a decent code review and so I didn't post it as answer. Firstly, it would change the api to become something different then current working code. Secondly, I didnt make any observation about the code itself and I don't think I will...

Comment: @slepic it technically is an observation about the code, even if it just pertains to the API... "_Answers need not cover every issue in every line of the code. [Short answers are acceptable](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1463/120114), as long as you explain your reasoning. Do not provide suggestions for improvements in a comment, even if your suggestion makes a very short answer._" From [What goes into an answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @slepic I understand that POST is created, my bad for not have mentioning this, but I used GET for simplistic reasons in this instance to create (via web browser request).

Comment: By the way, `addPerson` is not pure because it depends upon `set` which is impure.

Comment: @AaditMShah So even if it is an argument it would not be considered pure? In other words, impure functions can infect pure functions and make them impure?

Comment: Yes, impurity is exactly like an infection. Here's what the book [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/input-and-output) has to say about impurity, "That's why it's sort of _tainted_ with the `IO` type constructor and we can only get that data out in I/O code. And because I/O code is tainted too, any computation that depends on tainted I/O data will have a tainted result... So the taint of impurity spreads around much like the undead scourge and it's in our best interest to keep the I/O parts of our code as small as possible."

Comment: @AaditMShah I see. I'd like to think of writing FP code as trying to keep as much of the impure code to the edges of the applications as possible, preferably in the least amount of blocks of code to try to maximize the amount of pure code I write in other parts of the code. It is however pretty quiet when it comes to API designing hence my question here!